# Getting Error When implement the code push

Tags: reactjs, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I want to do CodePush Setup in my React Native Project, but I am getting this error.

i have done all the setup for codepush and when i run the code push command for both application (android/ios) i am getting this error.

`/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js`
`Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`